# find(1234) including relationships

Tags: zend-framework, zend-db-table

I am having a model "Events" (Zend_Db_Table_Abstract) that's got various relationships to other models. Usually I think I would do something like this to find it and its relationships:

```
$events = new Events();
$event = $events->find($id)->current();
$eventsRelationship1 = $event->findDependentRowset('Relationship1');
```

As the relationship is already set up I am wondering if there's any sort of automatic join available or something. Every time I fetch my event I need to have all the relationships, too. Currently I see only two ways to achieve that:

1. Build the query myself, hard coded. Don't like this, because it's working around the already set up relationship and "model method convenience".
2. Fetch every related object with a single query. This one's ugly, too, as I have to trigger too many queries.

This goes even a step further when thinking about getting a set of multiple rows. For a single event I may query the database multiple times, but when fetching 100 rows joins are just elementary.

So, does anyone know a way to create joins by using those relationships or is there no other way than hardcoding the query?

Thanks in advance

Arne

Answer (score 1):

The way to solve this challenge is to 'upgrade' your database access to use the [dataMapper](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataMapper.html) pattern.

You are essentially adding an extra layer between the model in your application an their representation in the db.  This mapper layer allows you read/write data from different tables - rather than a direct link between one model and one table.

Here is a [good tutorial](http://www.dragonbe.com/2010/01/zend-framework-data-models.html) to follow.  (There are some bits you can skip - I left out all the getters and setters as its just me using the code).

It takes a little while to get your head round the way it works, when you've just been using `Zend_Db_Table_Abstract`, but it is worth it.

Comment: http://www.survivethedeepend.com/zendframeworkbook/en/1.0/implementing.the.domain.model.entries.and.authors is another good read. By the way, this pattern allows you to use different sources with the same model (like i use a database-backend and a tex-backend for content while the frontend/controller doesn't see any difference :)